# RegEx Pattern Mactching

Tags: java, regex

To find the one digit hexadecimal Im using folloing pattern 
    "0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]"
and finding it in below source string 
    "12 0x 0x12 0Xf 0xg"
indexed from 0 to 17.

Output is 0 and 11 index.

I have a question, when data is consumed from left to right in a set of 3 letters, then 11th position match should not come then how this is identifying 11th position for hexadecimal no.

```
Pattern p6 = Pattern.compile("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]");
Matcher m6 = p6.matcher("12 0x 0x12 0Xf 0xg");
while(m6.find()) { System.out.print(m6.start( ));   
}
```

Comment: 11 is the character position of the start of `0Xf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

11 is the position of a valid hex, e.g. pattern matches. When your pattern has x characters, it doesn't mean, it will match only those starting at position y such that y = 0 (mod x).

On the other hand, they should not overlap, so for example having pattern "aaa", only posision 0 will be matched for string "aaaaa", but for "aaaaaa", it will be 0 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that because the regex will only match 3 letter matches, the regex engine will look at your string in groups of 3 letters, and therefore the start of matches can only be a multiple of 3. This is a misconception.

The regex engine will always advance 1 letter at a time, and check to see if it matches the pattern.

Your program produces the output 6 and 11, which is correct. I have put `|` at index 6 and 11. Index 0 is just before the first character. As you can see, they are at the start of matches.

```
12 0x |0x12 |0Xf 0xg
```